# Integral inequality 5

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality, integral-inequality

How can I prove that:

$$8\le \int _3^4\frac{x^2}{x-2}dx\le 9$$

My teacher advised me to find the asymptotes, why? what helps me if I find the asymptotes?

Comment: Asymptotes, or extrema?

Comment: Both, because if I find extrem points I will know monotony, that I know, but I don't understand why my teacher advised me to find asymptotes... for what?

Comment: You don't need asymptotes here. There aren't any on the interval of integration.

Comment: Exist integral inequality who need find asymptotes?

Comment: I encourage you to edit the question to choose a better title ( "Integral inequality 5" is not terribly descriptive).  Also, you might think about how to pose a question that is likely to be helpful to others again in the future.  For instance, "When does finding asymptotes help compute an integral, and how do I use the asymptotes to solve the integral?" seems more likely to be useful to others, as it applies to a broad class of situations -- not just that one specific integral.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The important point is that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x^2}{x-2}\right)<0$$
for $x\in[3,4]$, so that $\frac{x^2}{x-2}$ is decreasing there. Hence,
$$\int_3^4\frac{4^2}{4-2}dx\leq \int_3^4\frac{x^2}{x-2}dx\leq\int_3^4\frac{3^2}{3-2}dx,$$
and the left and right hand sides evaluate to $8$ and $9$ respectively.

Comment: Alternatively, to prove it is decreasing, note that $$\forall x\in [3,4]\left(\dfrac{x^2}{x-2}=x+2+\dfrac{4}{x-2}\right).$$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$$(b-a) m \leq \int_a^b f(x) \, dx \leq (b-a) M$$

where $m, M$ are the minimum and maximum of $f$ on $[a,b]$.

The asymptotes of this function occur around $x=2$, so I don't see why your teacher asks you to use them.

Comment: minimum is f(4) and maximum is f(0) ? for f(4)=8 and this is good but f(0)= 0 and I need 9

Comment: @AndreiMihai minimum *on the interval*.

Comment: Thank you very much guys! I have another inequality integral but I make a new ask question or can I put here?

Comment: If it is similar to this question, then I would try to do it yourself given the advice you got for this one. If you can't figure out, then post a new question.

Answer (score 4):

Direct approach is not so painful:
$$\int_{3}^{4}\frac{x^2}{x-2}\,dx = \int_{1}^{2}\frac{(x+2)^2}{x}\,dx = \int_{1}^{2}\left(x+4+\frac{4}{x}\right)\,dx =\frac{11}{2}+4\log 2 $$
and by the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality) we have:
$$ \log 2 =\int_{1}^{2}\frac{dx}{x} \in \left(\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{4}\right) $$
so:
$$\int_{3}^{4}\frac{x^2}{x-2}\,dx \in \left(8+\frac{1}{6},8+\frac{1}{2}\right).$$

Comment: But why theacher advise me to find asymptotes?

Comment: @AndreiMihai: honestly I don't know. The given inequality is quite crude and it can be approached in many ways.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Show that $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x-2}$ satisfies: $f(3)=9,$ $f(4)=8$ and $f$ is decreasing in the interval $[3,4].$